# Running Orleans 3 Silo Host in Windows Service with .Net Core

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, orleans

I am currently developing an Orleans 3 application, where I need to have the Silo Host as a Windows service. Normally I would use TopShelf to use host as a WindowsService.

However, with the new changes in .net core 3 (GenericHost) and Orleans 3 (UseOrleans), I thought something like this would work (I removed all the config code and just left the relevant parts):

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()

    .UseOrleans(builder => {...ConfigCode...})
    ...ConfigCode...
    .UseWindowsService();
```

Now with this setup Host starts and operates correctly when I start it by running the .exe file (or running via Visual Studio). However, when I install the executable as a Windows service, it starts without any problem, but right away it stops without an error message.

Has anybody managed to get the Orleans Silo Host running as Windows service via this method or should I go back to using TopShelf or a Worker?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to go on with TopShelf as it seems to be the proper way to do this at the moment.